# Apply Gobal Query Filter on FindAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, soft-delete, global-query-filter

I implemented a **soft-delete** query behaviour in my `ASP.NET Core API`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   //...
   modelBuilder.Entity<OneOfMyEntity>().HasQueryFilter(entity => !entity.IsDeleted);
   modelBuilder.Entity<AnotherEntity>().HasQueryFilter(entity => !entity.IsDeleted);
}
```

Now this works well in two of my frequently used methods in my `Repository` that encapsulates my `DbContext`:

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllExcludeDeleted()
{
   return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
}
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll()
{
   return await _context.Set<TEntity>().IgnoreQueryFilters().ToListAsync();
}
```

But then, when I was writing integration tests on my repository, I realized that it is not a solution for a `DbContext.FindAsync(int)` method:

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
{
   return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
}
```

**My solution**

I can imagine handling this problem with replacing `FindAsync(id)` with `FirstOrDefault(e => !e.IsDeleted)`

**Actual question**

What do you guys think, what would be a better solution than replacing `FindAsync` with a `Linq query`? Does `FirstOrDefault` has some **extreme performance downgrade** compared to `FindAsync`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Never, really? I would expect when the item is not in local cache, `Find{Async}` to be equivalent of `FirstOrDefault{Async}`, no?

Comment: `QueryFilter` may contain `EF.Functions` or something else, they cannot apply it to Find in local cache.

Comment: **In local cache** I said *when is **not** in local cache*. It definitely can and is using it in such scenario. So, saying *never* is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `FirstOrDefault` has some extreme performance downgrade compared to `FindAsync`?

Actually `Find{Async}` uses `FirstOrDefault{Async}` when the entity with specified key is not tracked (contained) in the local cache.

So the only benefit of `Find{Async}` is when used multiple times and the target entities are cached locally, as it avoids database trip.

From the other side, `Find{Async}` does not support eager loading (`Include` / `ThenInclude`), and usually is used in short lived contexts for one time seeks for a specific keys, so normally there is no real benefit of using it.

Another difference though, which has nothing to do with performance is that `Find{Async}` allows you to locate the new uncommit entities (with state `Added`), while all other methods query database and return only existing (or marked as `Deleted`) entities. But it can't and doesn't apply global query filters.

So it really depends of the concrete usage. I would say in most common cases you simply use `FirstOrDefault{Async}`, and in very rare cases - `Find{Async}`. I guess most of the "repository" examples use `Find{Async}` because it has more compact syntax, and not because of the performance or its primary purpose.